# Time limit exceeded even after doing an upper_bound on the array

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, binary-search

Language used : C++14.

I am given 2 sorted arrays A and B. Now, for each element in A i have to find a greater element in B if it is possible and note that once i have found an element in B for a particular element in A, i can only search ahead of that index in B .
I am doing something like this:

```
int j=0;
for(i=0;i < A.size();i++)
{
    int index = upper_bound(B.begin()+j,B.end(),A[i]) - B.begin();
    if(index>=B.size()){
        break;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"For A[]"<<A[i]<<" element "<<B[index]<<" is greater "<<"\n";
        j = index + 1;
    }
}
```

Even while i am doing a **binary search using upper_bound** still the program gives **Time limit exceeded** for large array ( say of size 1000000 ).

I cannot figure out the reason why?

**P.S : i know that this can be done using 2 pointers in linear time, however i wanted to know why my solution failed**. I am a new comer, so please help me out.

Comment: Even less then linear time: if A and B are sorted, you can look only at the last element of B. For every smaller element in A, this element in B will be greater. You can just run binary search on A: Le'ts say the last element in B is x. Find the index of highest element of A which is smaller then x (with binary search).

Comment: Sorry @Roim, for the confusion. Please see the updated question. I only want to search ahead of the element i found in B. Hope now it clears that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that the first iterator in your upper_bound is <= second iterator as it may happen that for some number the last element in array B is greater than it, so now if you do j = index + 1, it will be equal to B.end(), now searching for any greater element would always return some integer greater than length of B which is not possible.

Secondly, for your question :

```
int index = upper_bound(B.begin()+j,B.end(),A[i]) - B.begin();
```

This line is moving the first iterator by *'j' steps* first and *not in constant time* and then applying upper_bound would result in a time complexity of 
`o(n*n*log(n))`

n: for iterating over A

n: for moving by 'j' steps which in worst case can be n

log(n) : for upper_bound

which is causing Time Limit for larger arrays.

Comment: Ok thank you. Got it now. Spent much time for such a small thing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem buddy.

Comment: Unless the iterators aren't random access increasing then by j is a single operation